# SVN host vs using a web host

Tags: svn, host

Instead of using an SVN host like Assembla or Unfuddle, is it possible to use my own web host? Sorry for my ignorance, it's probably a stupid question because I haven't found an answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. If you are working alone you don't even need to setup a server, you create a repository with

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repository
```

And then access it as

```
svn checkout file:///path/to/repository
```

Otherwise you either use Subversion's builtin server or a full fledged web server. Several of the suppliers of [Subversion binary distributions](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) provide pre-packaged Apache/Subversion combinations.

Answer (score 1):

If you host your own web server then yes. It is just a matter of configuring svn to run as a service on the machine, or to work through apache for example.

If you are using a web hosting provider, it is not likely they will provide svn hosting as a service though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple web hosting for example [Web Hosting](http://www.netxplor.com) otherwise you can just use svnadmin create on your own server.